# bucket variables to the nearest bucket in r

Tags: r

I have a data set of random variable and I want to bucket these without changing the expectation so I can obtain a pdf. For example I have 100 random variables, say one of these are 48.75.

my buckets are 20 to 180 with increasing in increments of 2. so the nearest buckets are 48 and 50.

the probability of observing 48.75 is 1% (since 100 observation). so I want this probability assigned as
0.375 * 1% probability to 50 and 0.625 * 1% probability to 48

so that I can define a discrete pdf rather than a continuous pdf.

I have a vector of variables but I am having a really hard time finding the nearest buckets. I can code the probability assignment but main cause of my concern is this bucketing procedure.

```
MTM = rep(0,100)
for(i in 1:100){MTM[i] = 100+rnorm(1,sd=10)}
buckets = seq(20,180,2)
```

I was thinking of looping and doing something like:

```
1-min(abs(MTM[1]-buckets))
```

and searching for the point but I am stuck

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See `?cut`, and if you want more help than that share some data, simulated or otherwise.

Comment: that really helps. But the output of cut is a string so I can't do any mathematical operation.

Comment: You can change the output to a character vector and use regex to extract the numbers.

Comment: Yes, and as I said *show us some data* if you want more help.

Comment: `?findInterval` might help

Comment: code added to the question

Comment: The output of `cut` is NOT a "string" but rather a factor. (Please do learn some R.) Sounds line you instead want some variation on a linear interpolation and you should look at `?approx` (same help page as) `?approxfun`. There are also packages that implement fuzzy sets which your request also hints at wanting.

Answer (score 0):

buckets[which.min(abs(MTM[i]-buckets))]

this gives the index of the closest index, then it is straightforward.